# Genson: Handling child's properties while using RuntimePropertyFilter

Tags: java, json, genson

For my Genson configuration I used [`UrlQueryParamFilter`](https://github.com/owlike/genson/blob/genson-1.4/genson/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/ext/jaxrs/UrlQueryParamFilter.java). And it works, but not as I expected.
My entities:

```
public class Root {
    private String firstRootProp;
    private String secondRootProp;
    private List<Child> childs;

    //getters & setters
}

public class Child {
    private String firstChildProp;
    private String secondChildProp;

    //getters & setters
}
```

"rootEntity" endpoint binded to getting some `Root` instatnce in my rest service.
When I get `http://<host>/myservice/rootEntity?filter=childs` I excpected will get the all childs with all child's properties. But actually I got child's structure only:

```
{
    "childs": [
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

And what I want to get:

```
{
    "childs": [
        {
            "firstChildProp": "Some value for first property",
            "secondChildProp": "And some value for second property"
        },
        {
            "firstChildProp": "Some value for first property",
            "secondChildProp": "And some value for second property"
        }
    ]
}
```

**How can I fix it?**
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UrlQueryParamFilter expects you to provide the name of all the properties you want to include (or exclude if configured to exclude properties). So in short doing `http://<host>/myservice/rootEntity?filter=childs,firstChildProp,secondChildProp` should work.

I guess it could make sense to provide a way to configure the inclusion of all child properties, I opened this issue https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/105.